# Helm Grafana Default backend: default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-ingress, helm3, external-dns

I am trying to install Grafana using helm and external DNS controller. I am using alb_ingress_controller annotations. Following values I am using in values.yaml file for ingress.

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  # For Kubernetes >= 1.18 you should specify the ingress-controller via the field ingressClassName
  # See https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/#specifying-the-class-of-an-ingress
  # ingressClassName: nginx
  # Values can be templated
  annotations:
    {
      external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: charts.training-XX.XXXXXX.cloud,
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb,
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing,
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:XXXXXXXXXX:certificate/XXXXXX-XXXXX-a72c-XXXXXXXXXX,
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]',
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: XXX.XX.XX.XX/32
    }
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  labels: {}
  path: /grafana/
  backend:
    serviceName: grafana
    servicePort: grafana

  # pathType is only for k8s >= 1.1=
  pathType: Prefix

  hosts:
    - ""
  ## Extra paths to prepend to every host configuration. This is useful when working with annotation based services.
  extraPaths: []
```

issues: endpoints cannot be generated from ingress on external dns and

```
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
```